# how to make an object snap to another ojbect then follow its path with pure actionscript

Tags: flash, object, actionscript, air

I am currently trying to create an app using flash AIR.

I would like to find some more information on how to make an object snap to another ojbect then follow its path, eg. a person object is already on the stage, then drag an arrow to the object which snaps to it, then on play button it follows the arrow path. all in pure actionscript, no guide layers.

Any help is really appreciated. Or examples if there are any around.

Regards
Mark T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference in their positions, so make the follower object change its X property to ((frames_to_go-frames_passed)*starting_x_difference)+target_x between the objects. Same goes for the Y property.

Comment: do you have a small example to help me understand how this would work? please, im not the best with flash.

Comment: do you know of any examples that i could look at to help me with this?